# Add String from textEdit to a QStack

Tags: qt, split, stack, qstring, qstringlist

I am trying to capture the contents from `textEdit` and add it to a QStack. The content I am splitting so to be able to reverse the order of the sentence captured. I already have that part covered, but I want to be able to convert from QStringList to be pushed to the QStack. This is what I have:

```
    void notepad::on_actionReversed_Text_triggered()
{

    QString unreversed = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
    QStringList ready = unreversed.split(QRegExp("(\\s|\\n|\\r)+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);

    QStack<QString> stack;
    stack.push(ready);

    QString result;

    while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        result += stack.pop();
        ui->textEdit->setText(result);
    }


}
```

Comment: Presumably you get a compilation error with your usage of `push`. Yes? A good question would include the error message.

Comment: Actually it doesn’t give an error. It crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QStack::push`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstack.html#push) only takes objects of it's template type.

i.e. In your case you must push `QString`'s onto the `QStack<QString>`, and not a list.

So, iterate the list of strings pushing each one in turn.

```
foreach (const QString &str, ready) {
    stack.push(str);
}
```

---

Something else that is wrong is that you are updating `textEdit` *inside* the `for` loop. You actually want to build up the string in the loop and *afterwards* update the text.

```
QString result;
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    result += stack.pop();
}

ui->textEdit->setText(result);
```

---

An alternate answer could be to do away with the stack and just iterate the QStringList `ready` in reverse order to build up `result` string.